# Can a character take a reaction before their turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, initiative, reactions

Can a character use his reaction in the first round of combat before their turn? There is no surprise involved here.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Good first question!

Comment: Are you asking the same as: [Can a character react to an action and take a regular action in the same round?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104564/can-a-character-react-to-an-action-and-take-a-regular-action-in-the-same-round)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes, an unsurprised character may use their Reaction before their first turn

There are two relevant rules in the Player's Handbook, emphasis added for relevance:

> #### Reactions
>
> Certain special abilities, spells, and situations allow you to take a special action called a reaction. [...]
>
> **When you take a reaction, you can't take another one until the start of your next turn.** If the reaction interrupts another creature's turn, that creature can continue its turn right after the reaction.
>
> —PHB, pg. 190

> #### Surprise
>
> [...]
>
> If you're surprised, you can't move or take an action on your first turn of the combat, and **you can't take a reaction until that turn ends**. A member of a group can be surprised even if the other members aren't.
>
> —PHB, pg. 189

So between these two sections, we glean that the only point where a Reaction is "refreshed" is at the start of a character's turn; there's no explicit point where the "initial Reaction" is granted, therefore it is available before the character gains its turn.

The only scenario where a character would not gain their Reaction is if they are surprised, or otherwise under an explicit effect that denies use of a character's Reaction.

### A Character needs an action that allows them to use their Reaction

Most regular uses of Reactions are unaffected by occurring before the first turn a character takes (Attacks of Opportunities, *Counterspell*, etc.), but one common use is the Readied Action; per the rules, a character won't be able to react with a Ready Action, because they weren't able to *set it up in the first place* due to not having had their first turn yet.

Strictly RAW, "Actions in Combat" cannot be taken outside of Initiative order. Many DMs waive this restriction on a case-by-case basis because adjudicating this rule for every possible decision a character could make would be cumbersome, but as a general rule, allowing characters to Ready Action outside of combat, as a general rule, can lead to characters getting extra attacks, and is a concept that's *meant* to be encapsulated by Initiative order.

So unless your DM rules otherwise on the Ready Action, a character would not be able to use the Reaction granted by Ready Action before their first turn.

Comment: It might be worth emphasizing that the fact that being surprised prevents them from taking a reaction until after their first turn makes it clear that they would otherwise be able to take a reaction before their first turn. (You do quote this part, but I feel that pointing this out directly makes it pretty clear that your answer is right.)

Comment: Take it or leave it but a JC tweet  [explicitly agrees](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/930576922517499904).